# How to upload images on the order of selection?

Tags: php, sorting, upload

I have a field in a form where the user can select multiple images.

```
<input multiple="" title="Selecione as imagens" type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo[]" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg"/>
```

I would like the data to be written to the database in order that he selected files.

I tried the conventional. After POST I work with the data as follows:

```
 for($i = 0 ; $i<count($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"]) ; $i++){
        $pFoto = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($pFoto,$diretorio.$nomeArquivo);
        $pont = fopen($diretorio.$nomeArquivo,"rb");
        $dados[4][$i] = base64_encode(fread($pont,filesize($diretorio.$nomeArquivo)));
        $dados[5][$i] = $_FILES["arquivo"]["type"][$i];
        fclose($pont);
        }
```

Comment: yes it is, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried the conventional. After POST I work with the data as follows:


`for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"]); $i++) {

                $pFoto = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"][$i];

                move_uploaded_file($pFoto, $diretorio . $nomeArquivo);
                $pont = fopen($diretorio . $nomeArquivo, "rb");

                $dados[4][$i] = base64_encode(fread($pont, filesize($diretorio . $nomeArquivo)));
                $dados[5][$i] = $_FILES["arquivo"]["type"][$i];

                fclose($pont);
            }`

Comment: Did that not work out in the right order?

Comment: No. He is not saving in the right order. :/

Comment: **Dont rely on client side validation!!**